# Scanning an array of strings for match in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an array:

```
a = ["http://design.example.com", "http://www.domcx.com", "http://subr.com"]
```

and then I want to return true if one of the elements in that array matches the string:

```
s = "example.com"
```

I tried with `include?` and `any?`.

```
a.include? s
a.any?{|w| s=~ /#{w}/}
```

I don't know how to use it here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `any?` like:

```
[
  "http://design.example.com",
  "http://www.domcx.com",
  "http://subr.com"
].any?{ |s| s['example.com'] }
```

Substituting your variable names:

```
a = [
  "http://design.example.com",
  "http://www.domcx.com",
  "http://subr.com"
]
s = "example.com"
a.any?{ |i| i[s] }
```

You can do it several other ways also, but the advantage using `any?` is it will stop as soon as you get one hit, so it can be much faster if that hit occurs early in the list.

Comment: See [`str[matchstr]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). "If a match_str is given, that string is returned if it occurs in the string." It returns `nil` if nothing is found, or the sub-string, effectively triggering the `any?` with a false/true result. It's part of the wonderfulness of Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the link,never reached to the middle of the cluster of methods :)

Comment: Thanks for the match str method. your logic works for me. I need to get very first element in an array list if it is return true. I have written like a.any?{ |i| p i unless i[s] }. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How is the below:

```
a=["http://design.example.com", "http://www.domcx.com", "http://subr.com"]
s= "sus"
p a.any? { |w| w.include? s } #=> false

a=["http://design.example.com", "http://www.domcx.com", "http://subr.com"]
s= "design.example"
p a.any? { |w| w.include? s } #=>true

a=["http://design.example.com", "http://www.domcx.com", "http://subr.com"]
s= "desingn.example"
p a.any? { |w| w.include? s } #=>false

a=["http://design.example.com", "http://www.domcx.com", "http://subr.com"]
s= "example"
p a.any? { |w| w.include? s } #=>true

a=["http://design.example.com", "http://www.domcx.com", "http://subr.com"]
s= "example.com"
p a.any? { |w| w.include? s } #=>true
```